# Hide ngx-plyr controls

Tags: javascript, angular, plyr

i'm using plyr with this tag

```
<plyr style="display: block; width: 100%;" [plyrPlaysInline]="false" plyrTitle="Video 1" [plyrSources]="videoSources"
  (plyrInit)="player = $event" (plyrPlay)="played($event)" (plyrPause)="paused($event)">
```

i've done exactly like the tutorial said, but why the buttons appears like that? any thought?

[image]

Comment: Have you imported styles in `angular.json` from `"node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css"`?

Comment: i think i may have place that in the wrong place LoL i put it on `"test"` not on `"build"`, it fixed thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `angular.json` add the plyr css

```
"styles": [
    ...
   "node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css",
    ...
],
```